# iPhone / iPad macro or c function?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, macros

What's the best way to define the following ternary operator?

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone ? x : y
```

I considered using the macro

```
#define phonePad(x, y) ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone ? x : y)
```

But [this article](http://weblog.highorderbit.com/post/11656225202/appropriate-use-of-c-macros-for-objective-c-developers) mentions that it may not be the best idea. Is there a way to do the equivalent using a C function or is this the best way of implementing it?

Comment: could be either an object or a primitive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't use a macro for this. By using a macro, you require for the device to check the user interface idiom ever time this is used, and set x or y accordingly. Consider making a new method that returns based on the interface idiom. This can be static, because it's impossible for this value to ever change at runtime.

```
- (id)determineXOrY {
    static id obj = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        obj = [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone ? x : y
    });

    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Neither.

```
BOOL isiPhone = ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] 
                 == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone);

foo = isiPhone ? x : y;
bar = isiPhone ? xprime : yprime;
...
```

If you turn that into a macro, you'll get a bunch of unnecessary calls into the Objective-C runtime. So just cache the result. Plus, it'll probably be a lot easier to read if you just write plain C code instead of using a macro.

Answer (score 0):

If you do use the macro you must add some parentheses:

```
#define phonePad(x, y) ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone ? (x) : (y))
```

Without the parentheses you will have serious issues if `x` or `y` are more than simple values.

One downside to the macro is that you really need to be sure that both `x` and `y` evaluate to the same non-ambiguous data type.